# doxygen: how to output backticks in a code section

Tags: doxygen, backticks

i was wondering if it is possible to output backticks whithin a doxygen' code section.

```
~~~~~~~~~~
     for file in `ls dir/*.filter`
     do
     done
~~~~~~~~~~
```

I get no output at all. And this seems to be caused by the backtick "`" i've inserted into my code section.

Does anyone had the same issue. Any suggestion?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

` is used to create an inline code block. Instead, use \code, \endcode rather than a markdown code block.

for example

```
\code
this is an inline `code block with ` characters
\endcode
```

renders with the ` characters included.

[image]

When a pair of `s is encountered in the code, doxygen will not process whatever is between.

The following will render correctly:

```
\code
     for file in `ls dir/*.filter`
     do
     done
\endcode
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it.Sometimes the fenced code blocks that you were using seem to work better for me, for example, they will embed within a paragraph better (useful for saying \deprecated the following section is deprectate ~~~~ code ~~~~~. So I use both code block types in different situations.